# Android Options Menu full size box draws before transition finishes

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-optionsmenu

Just wondering if anyone else has encountered an issue when clicking on the three button options bar in toolbar/app bar where the full size box is shown before the transition animating has completed.

Checked a few different apps and it seems to be present in some, but not others. Anyone know how to remove this, or why it shows up? Thanks ahead of time! 
[image: shows box while options menu transitions]

Answer (score 0):

I case you've run into the same issue, I solved the problem by removing my

`<item name="android:background">@color/colorBack</item>`

in the value/styles for the corresponding ToolbarStyle. This applies the background drawable to every single view that doesn't have its own background, thus breaking things. Instead, I set the Toolbar background in the app_bar.xml attributes.

While this got me going in the right direction, I still had to go into my CustomPopupStyle and change

```
<item name="android:background">@color/color</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBack</item>
```

Works as intended after, no more box appearing before the transition completes.

Hope this helps.